# Asynchronous methods with EJB 3.0 and weblogic 11G

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb-3.0, weblogic11g

What is the correct way to call an EJB 3.0 ( weblogic 11G) in asynchronous way.

In Jboss exists Asynch

```
Echo asynchEcho = Asynch.getAsynchronousProxy(echo);
System.out.println("-------- Asynchronous call");
ret = asynchEcho.echo("asynchronous call");
System.out.println("Direct return of async invocation is: " + ret);
```

With EJB 3.1 we have @Asynchronous  annotation

But with EJB 3.0 what can I do? Weblogic 11G have something special?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Your example is essentially synchronous.